# Home Key pressed when not even touching it?

Tags: sony-xperia

I've been going insane since yesterday. When typing or selecting things on the bottom half of the screen, every so often the app I'm on erratically closes because the home key thinks it was pressed. I removed my scratched screen protector, but all that accomplished was the problem being more consistent.

I found that when ever I press/swipe my finger within 5-10mm above the home key, it activates and I'm back on the home screen. It's especially bad when my finger slows down, so I guess it stops registering the swipe and thinks I tapped.

Anyone having this problem on Android? Or do you think my phone is giving up the ghost? I tried booting in Safe Mode, still same problem.

Phone: Sony Xperia E4g

Android version: 4.4.4

Comment: Does this device have a hardware or on screen home button? I'm assuming on screen, but this site isn't about assumptions.

Comment: The home button is on screen

Answer (score 0):

If you have older firmware than `25.0.A.2.14` it's probably a software issue (check that link: [multitouch bug xperia e4g](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-E4/Sony-xperia-E4G-problem-with-multitouch/td-p/989043/page/4) Otherwise it's probably broken screen or another unknown software bug.. :(